# Sunburst plot - Error in generating more than 2 rings

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, conditional-statements

I have got this data set and want to generate a sunburst plot. The data is of 4 columns which are unit, weight, year16 and year17. The sunburst is based on the values in the weight column. The code is there and when adding the coding for the third layer it is giving me an error. I think the error is coming when I am adding the third layer.

```
    library("ggnewscale")
    library(ggplot2)
    #read file
    weight.eg = read.csv("Dummy Data.csv", header = FALSE, sep = 
    ";",encoding = "UTF-8") 

    #change column names
    colnames(weight.eg) <- c 
    ("unit","weight","year16","year17")

    #check the class
    sapply(weight.eg, class)
    #View(weight.eg)

    #as weight column is factor change into integer
    weight.eg$weight = as.numeric(levels(weight.eg$weight)) 
    [as.integer(weight.eg$weight)]
    weight.eg$year16 = as.numeric(levels(weight.eg$year16)) 
    [as.integer(weight.eg$year16)]
    weight.eg$year17 = as.numeric(levels(weight.eg$year17)) 
    [as.integer(weight.eg$year17)]
    #Nas are introduced, remove
    weight.eg <- na.omit(weight.eg)

    #Sum of the total weight
    sum_total_weight = sum(weight.eg$weight)
    #First layer
    firstLevel = weight.eg %>% summarize(total_weight=sum(weight))

    cs_fun <- function(x){(cumsum(x) + c(0, cumsum(head(x , -1))))/ 2}

    ggplot(weight.eg) +
    geom_col(data = firstLevel,
           aes(x = 1, y = total_weight)) +
    geom_text(data = firstLevel,
            aes(x = 1, y = total_weight / 2, 
                label = paste("Total Weight:", total_weight)),
            colour = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(x = 2, 
               y = weight, fill = weight),
           colour = "black", size = 0.6) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Weight", 
                      low = "white", high = "lightblue") +
    # Open up new fill scale for next ring
    new_scale_fill() +
    geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = cs_fun(weight), 
                label = paste(unit, weight))) +
    geom_col(aes(x = 3, y = weight, fill = year16), 
             size = 0.6, colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Year16", 
                      low = "red", high = "green") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(unit,year16), x = 3, 
                y = cs_fun(weight))) +
    #next ring
    new_scale_fill() +
    geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = cs_fun(weight), 
                label = paste(unit, weight))) +
    geom_col(aes(x = 4, y = weight, fill = year17), 
           size = 0.6, colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Year17", 
                      low = "red", high = "green") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(unit,year17), x = 4, 
                y = cs_fun(weight))) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

The output for `dput(weight.eg)` is

```
     structure(list(unit = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E", "F", "Unit"), class = "factor"), weight = c(30, 25, 
    10, 17, 5, 13), year16 = c(70, 80, 50, 30, 60, 40), year17 = c(50, 
    100, 20, 30, 70, 60)), .Names = c("unit", "weight", "year16", 
    "year17"), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame", na.action = 
    structure(1L, .Names = "1", class = "omit"))
```

I want to include year17 as well and in the future there will be 
     columns, so that has to be added as well. Because of the error I 
     am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: The plotting code runs without errors for me. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NewGeomCol' not found                                This is the error i am getting. I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Seems like an error within ggnewscale to me, since that package prefixes adjusted geoms with 'New'. Must year17 have it's own colourscale or could it be combined with the colourscale of year16? They seem to measure in the same unit, no? In that last case you can omit the latest `new_scale_fill()` and `scale_fill_gradient()` and have year17 be colourcoded like year16. Meanwhile, I'll think of some alternatives.

Comment: Perfect!! I removed the new_scale_fill() and scale_fill_gradient(). Now its working. So even if i have to add more layers, it will work right?

Comment: Yes, if the new layers are of the same type (have the same units) as year16 and year17 it should

Comment: Great!!! Thanks for the help